# How can I activate a Windows Reset from the Recovery Drive?

Tags: windows, settings, administrator

As the result of some missteps in setting up a new Windows PC, I now have just a local account. I have no Administrator account and I can not do any management actions. So now I want to do a reset to get back to the original OS state. I have a Recovery Drive with system files that I made when I first unboxed the new computer. I can boot from that but I can't continue the Reset without the missing Administrator password. Is there some way to activate the Reset from the Recovery Drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a new pc, why not wipe the whole hard drive and reinstall windows?
If it was a pre-built PC most of the times they come with its own 'recovery' partition which you can boot from and reinstall/etc.

Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I just did that today, and it worked. My problem until this morning was that to actually start the reset, you have to be an Administrator and I had no Administrator account available to use. But there was a old Adm account with a password nobody remembered, then this morning by trying all methods of restarts, I was presented with a sign in request with a Did you forget password? link and I reset the Adm password, started the OS reset, and was good to go. Thanks for your answer.